# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime never reaches selector on Swift 3

Tags: swift, avplayer, swift3

I'm adapting my app to Swift 3 and I'm encountering this problem. This used to work on Swift 2.2 but now it's broken. moviePlayBackFinished never gets called. I tried adding the observer in multiple ways, all without success.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.moviePlayBackFinished(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem);

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(moviePlayBackFinished(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem);

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.moviePlayBackFinished(sender:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem);

// (...)

@objc func moviePlayBackFinished(sender : AnyObject) {
    print("playbackFinished");
    let zeroCM : CMTime = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1000000000);
    playerLayer.player?.seek(to: zeroCM);
}

@objc func moviePlayBackFinished(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("playbackFinished");
    let zeroCM : CMTime = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1000000000);
    playerLayer.player?.seek(to: zeroCM);
}
```

Any ideas would be appriciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple possible reason of this issue.

```
NotificationCenter
    .default
    .addObserver(self, 
                 selector: #selector(self.moviePlayBackFinished(sender:)),
                 name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                 object: player.currentItem)
```

First of all, you have to set object to nil. `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notification automatically set object to the `AVPlayerItem` which reached at the end. If you change it manually, you will not get any notification of `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`.

Second, according to the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` documentation:

> **Important**
>
> This notification may be posted on a different thread than the one on which the observer was registered.

So, to make sure you should check the notification is on the thread you want.

It doens't matter you added observer from `UIViewController` or `AVPlayer` subclass.

Comment: Is there any documentation about 'AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime' notification atomically setting object to the AVPlayerItem? Because what is happening for me two playerItems are being delegated the end time message.

Comment: [Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime). It says `The notification’s object is the item that finished playing.`

Comment: I'm using AVQueuePlayer and this notification is fired only after first item in the queue finishes playing. selector not being called for any other items in the queue.

Comment: @SPS did you find solution ?

Comment: Setting set object to nil fixed it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use this code..

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(detailViewController.playw), name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

playw is function name you have to make function like

```
func playw(){
//do here whatever you want to do

    }
```

Still you've any problem you can ask me.

Comment: How to back on clicking on "Done" button in AVPlayer. ? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan is right!

It doesn't matter if you observe from a UIViewController or a AVPlayer subclass.

**Just simply use**

```
addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, object obj: Any?, queue: OperationQueue?, using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void)
```

**instead of**

```
addObserver(_ observer: Any, selector aSelector: Selector, name aName: NSNotification.Name?, object anObject: Any?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so the problem was that I was trying to add the observer from a subclass that contained the video, instead of adding it from the ViewController where the video view was contained.

So to fix this I basically moved the NotificationCenter.default.addObserver call to the UIViewController and presto, all solved.

Thank you all

Comment: This is not a correct answer. It must be a thread problem. According to the quick help documentation of `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`, `Important
This notification may be posted on a different thread than the one on which the observer was registered.`. One easy fix for this will be using block based NSNotificationCenter observing.